# select the data by month and years in R

Tags: r, select

I have a data frame ordered by month and year. I want to select only the integer number of years i.e. if the data start in July 2002 and ends in September 2010 then select only data from July 2002 to June 2010.
And if the data starts in September 1992 and ends in March 2000 then select only data from September 1992 to August 1999. Regardless of the missing months in between.

The data can be uploaded from the following link:
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11XSLKX4EBwwkMtU_eU2iiDzasZrz4N5B/view?usp=sharing)

The code

```
mydata <- read.csv("E:/mydata.csv", stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

this is manually selection

```
selected.data <- mydata[1:73,]   # July 2002 to June 2010
```

how to achieve that by coding.

Comment: @ Ronak Shah usually year start in Jan and ends in Dec (12) months. But if the data starts by July so I want to select the June ending. July 2002 to June 2003 this is one integer year and the second integer year is July 2003 to June 2004 and so on till the last row. in mydata we see that the data ends in Sept 2010 and is supposed to end in June 2010.  to find the months that I want to keep, by adding 12 to the start month. if it is July then select till June. if it is May select till April and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base solution, that reproduce your manual subsetting:

```
mydata <- read.csv("D:/mydata.csv", stringsAsFactors=F)
lookup <-
  c(
    January = 1,
    February = 2,
    March = 4,
    April = 4,
    May = 5,
    June = 6,
    July = 7,
    August = 8,
    September = 9,
    October = 10,
    November = 11,
    December = 12
  )
mydata$Month <- unlist(lapply(mydata$Month, function(x) lookup[match(x, names(lookup))]))

first.month <- mydata$Month[1]
last.year <- max(mydata$Year)
mydata[1:which(mydata$Month==(first.month -1)&mydata$Year==last.year),]
```

Basically, I convert the Month name in number and find the month preceding the first month that appears in the dataframe, for the last year of the dataframe.

Comment: @ Elia one more question, if the last year does not contain e.g. June (it is missing) in this case I need if statement to back to the previous year of the last year. How can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R one-liner :

```
result <- mydata[seq_len(with(mydata, which(Month == month.name[match(Month[1],
                         month.name) - 1] & Year == max(Year)))), ]

head(result)

#     Month Year       var
#1     July 2002 -91.22997
#2  October 2002 -91.19007
#3 December 2002 -91.05395
#4 February 2003 -91.16958
#5    March 2003 -91.17881
#6    April 2003 -91.15110

tail(result)
#      Month Year       var
#68 December 2009 -90.92610
#69  January 2010 -91.07379
#70 February 2010 -91.12460
#71    March 2010 -91.10288
#72    April 2010 -91.06040
#73     June 2010 -90.94212
```

Comment: Your code works well in case of the start month anything but January, but if January was the first month in the column(Month) then when subtracting 1 from it will give 0. Any idea of how to deal with this issue?